# pip install persistently downloading torch while I have one locally installed

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I am on a specific conda environment with the following torch library installed:

```
pip freeze
torch @ file:///home/ttt/tools/pytorch/dist/torch-2.0.0a0%2Bgite9ebda2-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl#sha256=536fb5f48ebb5e5ec25a0be82e98f71699edff288fa752f1e07f78b550239797
```

When I want to install a specific project that has torch as a dependency like this in the pyproject.toml file:

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "torch" ]
```

When I do pip install It will always  download torch from online and make my project depend on that.

I have tried to replace torch to include version etc, it won't work unless I do the following:

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "torch @ file:///home/ttt/tools/pytorch/dist/torch-2.0.0a0%2Bgite9ebda2-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl#sha256=536fb5f48ebb5e5ec25a0be82e98f71699edff288fa752f1e07f78b550239797"
]
```

But that is a problematic as such file cannot be generalized for other co-authors. Provided that we all install the same wheel file in a conda environment, how can we generalize the above so pip install always picks the torch version installed by the wheel file and not fetches it from the internet.

Comment: Does the build run directly on your local machine, or does it run inside a container?

Comment: on my local machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this and let's see if it works for you. If you want to ensure that pip always uses the locally installed version of torch from the wheel file rather than fetching it from the internet, you can specify it as a dependency in your pyproject.toml file using a more general approach. Instead of specifying a specific file path to the wheel, you can use the torch package name and specify a local URL using the --find-links option when running pip install. This way, you won't need to hardcode the specific file path in your project configuration.

Here's how you can do it:

Organize your project directory like this:

```
my_project/
├── pyproject.toml
└── torch_wheel/
    ├── torch-2.0.0a0+gite9ebda2-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
    └── torch-2.0.0a0+gite9ebda2-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl.sha256
```

In your pyproject.toml file, specify the torch dependency like this:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["torch"]
```

When installing your project, use the --find-links option to specify the local directory containing the torch wheel file:

```
pip install --find-links=torch_wheel/ my_project/
```

By using the --find-links option, you tell pip to look for dependencies in the specified directory first before attempting to fetch them from the internet. This allows you to use a general project configuration while ensuring that pip uses the locally installed torch wheel file. You and your co-authors can use the same approach, and as long as you maintain the directory structure and the wheel file is available locally, pip will pick it up without the need for hardcoded file paths. I hope this helps you with solving the problem